# Colored text in content boxes

Tags: css, wordpress

I'm trying to create content boxes with each one having different text color, but i'm unable to do it

here is code

```
.content-box-blue,
.content-box-green, {
margin: 0 0 25px;
overflow: hidden;
padding: 20px;
}
.content-box-blue {
color: #0000FF;
background-color: #d8ecf7;
border: 1px solid #afcde3;
}
.content-box-green {
color: #088A08;
background-color: #d9edc2;
border: 1px solid #b2ce96;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
.content-box-blue,.content-box-green, { you have used comma before { brackets thats why css is not working .
```

**CSS :**

```css
.content-box-blue,
.content-box-green {
margin: 0 0 25px;
overflow: hidden;
padding: 20px;
height: 100px;
width: 200px;
}
.content-box-blue {
color: #0000FF;
background-color: #d8ecf7;
border: 1px solid #afcde3;
}
.content-box-green {
color: #088A08;
background-color: #d9edc2;
border: 1px solid #b2ce96;
}

**HTML:**
```

```html
<div class="content-box-blue">
  This text box is 
</div>
<div class="content-box-green">
  This text box is 
</div>
```

Comment: thanks, after testing on another theme ,it seem that there is a bug in my current theme that was why it wasn't working